# Is there a way to include LaTeX in a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, latex

So I am working on a project to generate documents using LaTeX, the program is supposed to ask for some inputs and then compile the .tex and get a .pdf.

The problem is that if I use QProcess to compile the .tex using terminal commands, LaTeX must be installed on the PC to work. So I was wondering if there's a way to include LaTeX in my app so I can compile .tex files without installing LaTeX on every PC. And how LaTeX online editors compile .tex?

Comment: Qt doesn't have built-in support for LaTeX as far as I know, but there's plenty of LaTeX processing libraries out there.

Comment: @MrEricSir could you name one library?